# How to format the Duration object in Swift

Tags: swift

Swift released a new [Duration](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration) object that is "a representation of high precision time."

I'm using it like this:

```
let clock = ContinuousClock()

let duration = clock.measure {
    // Code or function call to measure here
}

print("Duration: \(duration)")
```

If the duration really short it prints out something like this:
`8.2584e-05 seconds`

Instead of scientific notation, I would like to always display as seconds: `0.000082584 seconds`

Does anyone know how to always keep the format in seconds?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like `Date`s, `Duration`s support the [`formatted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/formatted(_:)?changes=_8) method. You can give it either the [`TimeFormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/timeformatstyle?changes=_8) ([`time`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/timeformatstyle/time(pattern:))) or [`UnitsFormatStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/unitsformatstyle?changes=_8) ([`units`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/unitsformatstyle/units(allowed:width:maximumunitcount:zerovalueunits:valuelength:fractionalpart:))). For your desired format, it looks like the latter is more suitable. You basically want a `fractionalPart` that has a very large allowed length.

Though from my experiments, it still rounds everything to nanosecond-precision, even though `Duration` can support higher precisions. This is perhaps because nanoseconds is the smallest supported unit in [`Duration.UnitsFormatStyle.Unit`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/duration/unitsformatstyle/unit?changes=_8).

For example:

```
let duration: Duration = .nanoseconds(1234)
print(
    duration.formatted(.units(
        width: .wide, 
        fractionalPart: .init(lengthLimits: 1...1000)
    ))
)
```

Output:

```
0.000001234 seconds
```

By default, this will also include hours and minutes if the duration is long enough. If you don't want that, pass `allowed: [.seconds]` as the first parameter:

```
duration.formatted(.units(
    allowed: [.seconds],
    width: .wide,
    fractionalPart: .init(lengthLimits: 1...1000)
))
```